# How to register residency in Germany

Tags: germany, residency, rental

I'm Italian and I'm moving to Germany for work; I will also take my wife and 4 year old son.
  How do I proceed to register residency? And once I register can my son go to school right away?

Details: Do I need a proper rent contract? Right now I don't have a rent contract since I've reserved an Airbnb; and I actually intend on staying in this same Airbnb at least until the end of the year (since my project is expected to end in December or January, if it extends or if I get another project or longer term employment then I'll probably look for a permanent place (buy or long'period rent) but right now I can't make a long term commitment).

Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to register without having a rental agreement? What documents did you need to register?

Comment: hi Rhei, yes! I managed to register using a document called "Wohnungsgeberbestätigung gemäß § 19 des Bundesmeldegesetzes (BMG)". This one: https://www.dresden.de/media/pdf/einwohner/WGBest__Formular.pdf  hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, EU citizens can stay in another EU country (e.g. Germany) up to three months without registering. If you know you want to stay longer, you have to register at the authorities of the town you live in, which are usually called Bürgeramt, Bürgerbüro or similar, and may be situated in the Stadthaus or Rathaus. You will find the address on your town's web site.

To register you need a Vermieterbescheinigung (if you have a rent contract). In my town it was also possible to let a third person confirm that you live in his or her house. Just ask for this form at the Bürgeramt.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ok... so if I don't have a rent contract; I'll need the owner to confirm that he's letting me stay in there or is it just a form that he will need to sign? Will he or I have to pay anything (like a % of the amount that I'll pay to him or any tax...)?

Comment: I think "up to three months without registering" applies when you don't become a resident, that is you leave before the end of the three months. If you become a resident you need to register within a week or two. And if you stay four months, you are a resident from day one.

Comment: Registration is free. The landlord has to fill out the forms for free. Not filling out the forms would be highly illegal for him.

Comment: Great, thank you both very much! I'm too new at this stack exchange to give the upvotes, but my question's answered.

Answer (score 1):

The registration is the most important thing to do after arriving to Germany. Once you do it:

- your children are elligible for German schools and adaptation courses
- you can open bank account
- you can register for social security and tax number (without it, you can't legally work in Germany)

However, if your children are not fluent in German, consider letting them stay in Italy until you know if you'll get a permanent position. Adapting to new language environment is quite stressful even for an adult. German schools are prepared to deal with children who are need to be taught German, but it might be difficult for a child being unable to freely communicate with other children.